# npm error while install the package which contains the sqlite3 in its package.json

Tags: npm, node-sqlite3

when i try to install the package with this way

`npm install -g package_name`

my sqlite3 version is 5.1.6
node version 18.17.1
npm version 9.6.7

package_name package contains the sqlite3 as a dependency

i can see that it is downloading packages when it will try to download sqlite3 it is giving me this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\username\package_name\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@RajMarutitech\github-insight-cli-app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@RajMarutitech\github-insight-cli-app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64 --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@RajMarutitech\github-insight-cli-app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/releases/download/v5.1.6/napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info install unpacking napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64/node_sqlite3.node
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for sqlite3@5.1.6 and node@18.17.1 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.5 found at "C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.4.33213.308) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:369:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:390:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:427:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\RAJ RAMANI\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@RajMarutitech\\github-insight-cli-app\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\RAJ RAMANI\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@RajMarutitech\\github-insight-cli-app\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@RajMarutitech\github-insight-cli-app\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@RajMarutitech\github-insight-cli-app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@RajMarutitech\github-insight-cli-app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64 --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@RajMarutitech\github-insight-cli-app\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\RAJ RAMANI\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@RajMarutitech\\github-insight-cli-app\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@RajMarutitech\github-insight-cli-app\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-14T12_00_37_209Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI>npm config set msvs_version 2019
npm ERR! `msvs_version` is not a valid npm option

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\RAJ RAMANI\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-14T12_10_24_491Z-debug-0.log
```

i have tried to install the python in my pc but still it gives me that error.